# my app with broadcast receiver and wifi

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I, this is my firt app with android and i'm trying to comunicate with hardware because for me it's exciting!

when i disable wifi or i change network.... i need to make toast and vibrate. what's wrong???

i test my app with galaxy s2 4.1.2 but i want my app able to run on old phones with android 2.3.3.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="dado.wifibc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver 
        android:name="dado.wifibc.BroadCastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

BroadCastReceiver.java

```
package dado.wifibc;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "blablabla!!!.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)   context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
}

}
```

Comment: `i want my app able to run on old phones with android 2.3.3.` So, what is the problem? Please add a question to your post.

Answer (score 0):

pls, remove action from intent filter and set action as"android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" like,

```
      <receiver 
    android:name="dado.wifibc.BroadCastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>

    </intent-filter>
```

and onReceive(),

```
           final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                    if (!wifi.isAvailable())
             {

              Toast.makeText(context, "blablabla!!!.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Vibrate the mobile phone
         Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)   context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
  }
```